# Сделать доступным Websocket в локальной сети

Tags: node.js, websocket

Пишу программу-клиент для WI-FI модуля ESP8266. Передача данных на сервер будет осуществляться посредством websocket. Для первоначальной отладки нужен websocket-сервер на локальном компьютере. Попытался сделать с помощью node.js  Скажу сразу с js я знаком мало. ОС Windows7. Поставил сервер с помощью примера ниже. Он работает, но на localhost. Мне нужно поднять его на локальном ip (Например 192.168.0.103). Как сменить ip в коде я не разобрался. Прошу помочь с этим кодом или может есть какая-либо другая альтернатива. Заранее спасибо.

```js
var http = require('http');
var Static = require('node-static');
var WebSocketServer = new require('ws');

// подключенные клиенты
var clients = {};

var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({port: 8081});
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {

  var id = Math.random();
  clients[id] = ws;
  console.log("новое соединение " + id);

  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('получено сообщение ' + message);

    for(var key in clients) {
      clients[key].send(message);
    }
  });

  ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log('соединение закрыто ' + id);
    delete clients[id];
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего менять не нужно. Поднятый на localhost сервер должен отываться при обращении по локальному адресу. Если не отвечает - копайте свой брандмауер и фаерволл

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек! Действительно так и есть, открыл нужный порт и все заработало!